# Release APK behaving differently from Debug APK

Tags: debugging, asynchronous, flutter, release, future

I have an app that gets the list of data from sqflite and it is working properly on debug mode or if I install the debug apk. However, when I install the release apk, it seems the data was not fetched and as a result, my app crashes. Is there anything that I overlooked when installing the release app? My assumption is that both debug and release should work the same.

Here's my flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.3.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.26.1)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.35.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: In debug mode there is no error so I can't put stacktrace. The problem is in the installed "release" version of the app.

Comment: I am suspecting that there is something wrong with the database in release apk or something like permission but I already tried adding WRITE and READ just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you define all the user permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file also.

Specifically `INTERNET` permission.

```
// AndroidManifest.xml
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
```